# Dejó de funcionar el resaltado de errores en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

No sé que le pasó al android studio: de un momento a otro, dejó de funcionar el resaltado de errores en el código a medida que escribo.

No sé cómo activarlo nuevamente para que me aparezcan los errores de código cuando estoy programando, que me serían de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

La mayoría de las ocasiones es debido a que `Power Save Mode` (modo: ahorro de energía) esta habilitado, para deshabilitarlo ve a  `Current inspection profile`, (esquina inferior izquierda en Android Studio) que es el iconito de un inspector :).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Otra causa es debido a que no se tiene suficiente memoria.

Answer (score 1):

Solucion como uso linux me elimine la carpeta de configuración de andrid estudio .android que se crea oculta en la carpeta personal

Comment: Lo que realiza esto es precisamente que **restaura la configuración original  que incluye [Power Save Mode deshabilitado.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/5256/95)**

Answer (score 0):

Una de las razones por la que esto pasa es por el "Modo Ahorro de Energía" o Power Save Mode.

Para verificarlo menu `File -> Power Save Mode`, debe estar sin la marca de activado, como la imagen abajo. (En español seria Archivo -> Modo Ahorro de Energía)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si esto no es el problema, ve al menu `File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings` y ya estando ahí adentro, entra `Editor -> Inspections`, veras la lista completa de inspecciones que están activadas/desactivadas, pero es poco probable que hayas pasado por ahí. Saludos.